# How do I nest quotes in VLC (command line)?

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player

I've got a multi-program input.  I want to take each of the programs and transcode each of them separately (because one is 16:9, one is 4:3) and then RTP each of the streams to a different address.

The problem is that I can't figure out a way to nest quotes in a way that is acceptable to VLC.  Mostly this is because I need to not only transcode and RTP, but also select the program.

```
cvlc multi-program-input-source.ts 
--sout '#duplicate{
  dst="transcode{width=640,height=360,OTHER_SETTINGS}:rtp{mux=ts,dst=SOMEWHERE,port=20000},select="program=3"",
  dst="transcode{width=704,height=480,OTHER_SETTINGS}:rtp{mux=ts,dst=SOMEWHERE,port=20002},select="program=4""
}'
```

I'm open to any solution, but if there is a way to select the program without quotes or in a way that I could nest them, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper format is to end the "dst" with a double-quote and then quote the select statement.

```
cvlc multi-program-input-source.ts 
--sout '#duplicate{
  dst="transcode{width=640,height=360,OTHER_SETTINGS}:rtp{mux=ts,dst=SOMEWHERE,port=20000}",select="program=3",
  dst="transcode{width=704,height=480,OTHER_SETTINGS}:rtp{mux=ts,dst=SOMEWHERE,port=20002}",select="program=4"
}'
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure this will work, but in a lot of operating systems, you can escape the inner quotes with a backslash (\"). So it would look like this:

```
cvlc multi-program-input-source.ts 
--sout '#duplicate{
  dst=\"transcode{width=640,height=360,OTHER_SETTINGS}:rtp{mux=ts,dst=SOMEWHERE,port=20000},select=\"program=3\"",
  dst="transcode{width=704,height=480,OTHER_SETTINGS}:rtp{mux=ts,dst=SOMEWHERE,port=20002},select=\"program=4\""
}'
```

I may have messed up which double quotes need escaped, but hopefully escaping the inner sets with \" will work for you.